# How to get FontFamily name (string) from TypeFace programatically in Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, typeface

My requirement is to get FontFamily name of Text view,

Example: if font family is "calibri", how to get that programatically without exposing any string property.

`textView.Typeface = Typeface.Create("Calibri", TypefaceStyle.Normal);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the fontFamily name from TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37137234/how-to-get-the-fontfamily-name-from-textview)