# How to get Font family of textView

Tags: android, textview, font-family

I have a `textview`,I just want to get the font family from that `textview` and set in another `textView`. I have created a textview programmatically. If it is possible then how to Implement it.

Comment: have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37137234/how-to-get-the-fontfamily-name-from-textview

Comment: yes,i have checked it,textview.getTag() return null value